# torch model evaluate from string

Tags: pytorch, torch

I do evaluation of my `torch` model loading a batch from text files:

```
def batchify(data, bsz):
    nbatch = data.size(0)
    data = data.narrow(0, 0, nbatch * bsz)
    data = data.view(bsz, -1)
    return data

def load_file(path, vocab, direction):
    lines = open(path).readlines()
    data = list(''.join(lines))
    idx = vocab['char'].map(data)
    if direction == 'backward': idx = idx[::-1]
    return torch.tensor(idx)

def load_data(path, vocab, direction):
    data = load_file(path, vocab, direction)
    yield data
```

This works ok:

```
eval_file_or_dir = os.path.join(BASE_PATH,'shakespeare.txt')
data = load_data(eval_file, vocab, direction)
if isinstance(data, GeneratorType):
    data = list(data)
    data = data[0]
batches = batchify(data, batch_size)
```

and I get `torch.Size([100, 6])`

Now, I want to load data from a string, so I wrote

```
def load_text(text, vocab, direction):
    buf = io.StringIO(text)
    lines = buf.readlines()
    data = list(''.join(lines))
    idx = vocab['char'].map(data)
    if direction == 'backward': idx = idx[::-1]
    yield torch.tensor(idx)
```

but it does not work as expected:

```
data = load_text(text, vocab, direction)
if isinstance(data, GeneratorType):
    data = list(data)
    data = data[0]
batches = batchify(data, batch_size)
print(batches, batches.size())
```

and I get a empty `tensor`:

```
tensor([], size=(100, 0), dtype=torch.int64) torch.Size([100, 0])
```